# Rails displaying joined table in each loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, each

I have Client and Task models, and I defined the relationships (Task `belongs_to :client`, and Client `has_many :tasks`).
In my tasks views, I manage to get data from the clients table (for instance `@task.client.name` works fine.
But when I iterate over all the results (`@tasks.each do |task|`) I can't access the clients table anymore: `task.client.name` throws an error:

> undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

So obviously the `client` method doesn't work on `task`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify that all your tasks have a client. If you need to enforce this in your model, provide a validation in your `Task` model

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
  validates :client, presence: true
end
```

Comment: They do. I added the validation anyway: same error.

Comment: @user3741713, you might have Task records that were already created even before you added the validation, which meant that the .each loop works, but suddenly at least one might have been missing the associated client record, thereby raising the error. Can you verify all of your Task records have a Client with the following code? `puts Task.all.collect { task.client.blank? ? task.id : nil }.compact` this returns all task with missing client record

Comment: I think you have an orphan task ie without client in your tasks. You can avoid error by using try task.try(:client).try(:name). But it's only a workaround. IMO, You have to verify your dataset.

Comment: Thanks, I had a task without a client_id indeed!